# What's the best tool for Javascript security auditing?

Tags: javascript, security, audit

Something that can at least scan a batch of .js files looking for eval statements and other questionable code. Maybe just a regex pattern would do it, but I'd like to find a more sophisticated (and regularly maintained) tool.

Comment: Why don't you try over on http://security.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: There is a security SE now? Jesus, how is one expected to keep up with this.

Answer (score 3):

old topic but new tool :
ScanJS, developed by mozilla in order to check the Firefox OS security.
https://github.com/mozilla/scanjs

Comment: FYI ScanJS has been deprecated as of July 2015.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned on the github, the new project is located at [https://github.com/mozfreddyb/eslint-config-scanjs](https://github.com/mozfreddyb/eslint-config-scanjs)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Douglas Crockford's JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/)? Although it doesn't scan your code for security problems, however, it does alert you on "eval" statements. OTOH, Predrag Tomasevic has wrote a [JavaScript Verifier based on JSLint](http://jslint.codeplex.com/) that can be integrated with Visual Studio (read more on this [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/JSLintVS.aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any Open Source tools that conduct static analysis of JavaScript.

Grepping for eval() likely isn't going to help for anything other than very simple, very obvious mistakes. It'll be even more difficult to analyze if the script has been minified or obfuscated because you'll be hard-pressed to determine if the argument is being used safely or not.

There are plenty of security problems in JavaScript that rely on the interaction with the DOM. Grepping for eval() might work, but it'll miss other execution points like hrefs or event handlers that might be attacked, e.g. *href=javascript:xss* or *onFoo=xss*. You really need a tool that deals with JavaScript and the DOM, not just a JavaScript console.

IBM/Watchfire recently released a paper about a [JavaScript analyzer](http://blog.watchfire.com/wfblog/2011/01/close-encounters-of-the-third-kind.html) they've created. The paper provides details on results rather than implementation. A commercial tool might not be the way you want to go, but the paper should help shed more light on the challenges of doing this well.

Answer (score 0):

This tool from Facebook seems promising.

https://github.com/facebook/jsgrep